# Formatting of data extracted from database

Tags: excel, vba

Am dumping the following dataset from an SQL Server database to an Excel spreadsheet using Excel VBA (please excuse formatting, but cannot paste image ):

```
CLC_Yr  IND_Period NMR_Company      NMR_TourType CLC_AccountType  CLC_RecCategory  REC_3TableCategory   Total
 2014      2         00010                       FIT                 Sales                1.2                                                    327,964.71
 2014      2         00010                       FIT                 Sales                1.3                               3.1.1                            395,062.92
 2014      2         00010                       FIT                 Sales                1.3                               3.1.2.1               30,783,438.87
 2014      2         00010                       FIT                 Sales                1.3                               3.1.2.2          397,434.81
 2014      2         00010                       FIT                 Sales                1.3                               3.1.3                           354,248.45
 2014      2         00010                       FIT                 COS                1.5                                                2,752,042.61
 2014      2         00010                       FIT                 COS                 1.6                               3.2.1                        1,145,008.75
 2014      2         00010                       FIT                 COS                 1.6                               3.2.2.1               25,376,372.13
 2014      2         00010                       FIT                 COS                 1.6                               3.2.3                         2,121,651.62
 2014      2         00010                       FIT                 Total                                                                              63,653,224.87
 2014      2         00010                       GRP                  Sales                 1.2                                                               340,682.10
 2014      2         00010                       GRP                  COS                  1.5                                                               695,162.13
 2014      2         00010                       GRP                  Total                                                                              1,035,844.23
 2014      2         00010                       COMP                  Total                                                                           64,689,069.10

 2014      2         00070                     GRP                  Sales                  1.2                                                         268,522.54
 2014      2         00070                       GRP                  COS                   1.5                                              250,493.17
 2014      2         00070                       GRP                  Total                                                                                 519,015.71
 2014      2         00070                       COMP                   Total                                                                     519,015.71
```

For each Company, we have various detail lines (NMR_TourType FIT/GRP and CLC_AccountType Sales/COS) with subtotals for FIT Total and GRP Total followed by an overall Company Total COMP Total.
Not every Company will have both the FIT and GRP detail lines - so in the above sample Company 00010 does have FIT and GRP detail lines and so will contain a 'FIT Total'
and a 'GRP Total', but Company 00070 only has GRP detail lines and so only has a 'GRP Total'.

The database table is being populated correctly and currently being dumped to an Excel spreadsheet using some simple Excel VBA code

```
stSQL = "SELECT CLC_Yr, IND_Period, NMR_Company, " & _
            "CASE WHEN NMR_TourType = '' THEN 'COMP' ELSE NMR_TourType END AS NMR_TourType, " & _
            "CASE WHEN CLC_AccountType = '' THEN 'Total' ELSE CLC_AccountType END AS CLC_AccountType, " & _
            "CLC_RecCategory, REC_3TableCategory, " & _
            "[CLC_Company_Value]  AS Total " & _
            "FROM [ReportDB].dbo.[ray_report_totals] "

Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection

    With cnt
         .CursorLocation = adUseClient
         .Open stADO
         .CommandTimeout = 0
        Set rst = .Execute(stSQL)
    End With

' Set up a reference to the Report Figures Worksheet
Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("Report Figures")

' Clear out our data area as this is refreshed on each load of spreadsheet 
wsSheet.Range("a10:q600").ClearContents

' On the Report Figures Worksheet we will dump the data starting from Cell A10
With wsSheet
     Set rnStart = .Range("A10")
End With

' Now dump the Recordset data to the sheet from A10 
rnStart.CopyFromRecordset rst
```

That all works fine, but using Excel VBA, I'd like to do some more formatting to the spreadsheet.

So, as per the dataset, the data on the spreadsheet will have, for each Company, various detail lines (NMR_TourType FIT/GRP and CLC_AccountType Sales/COS) with subtotals for FIT Total and GRP Total followed by an overall Company Total COMP Total.
Not every Company will have both the FIT and GRP detail lines - so in the above sample Company 00010 does have FIT and GRP detail lines and so will contain a 'FIT Total'
and a 'GRP Total', but Company 00070 only has GRP detail lines and so only has a 'GRP Total'.

The formatting I'd like to apply in Excel VBA is :

```
a) Blank out the Company number when the same number is repeated across multiple entries, so it only appears on the first entry for that Company;
b) For the 'FIT Total', 'GRP Total' and 'COMP Total' lines have the text appear as Bold, and possibly even changes the background colour of the row to green;
c) Have a blank line after each 'COMP Total' line before the next set of entries for another Company
```

I'm hoping that I'll be able to implement this formatting in Excel VBA, and would appreciate some specific Excel VBA guidance here, as this is beyond my current basic knowledge of Excel VBA.

Thanks

Ray

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to learn macro formating is to use the macro record tool.  That said, this code may work for you.

```
Sub FormatSheet1()
Dim BlnkLn As String, Cmpn As String, LastRow As Long
Dim RCnt As Long, MovCnt As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
MovCnt = 2
RCnt = 2
BlnkLn = "COMP"
Range("D2").Select
CName = ActiveCell.Address
Cmpn = Range(CName).Value
Do Until RCnt > LastRow 'run thru all the companies
    Do Until Cmpn = BlnkLn 'find all the same company
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        CName = ActiveCell.Address
        Cmpn = Range(CName).Value
        RCnt = RCnt + 1
    Loop
Range(Cells(MovCnt, "C"), Cells(RCnt - 1, "C")).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range(Cells(RCnt, "A"), Cells(RCnt, "H")).Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True ' format the COMP line
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5296274
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Range(Cells(RCnt + 1, "A"), Cells(RCnt + 1, "H")).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
With Selection.Interior ' insert and format line between companies
    .Pattern = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
LastRow = LastRow + 1
RCnt = RCnt + 2
MovCnt = RCnt
Range(Cells(RCnt, "D"), Cells(RCnt, "D")).Select
CName = ActiveCell.Address
Cmpn = Range(CName).Value
Loop
End Sub
```